# Max, Min, Avg function for an array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am being tasked with writing a function that takes as parameters an array of doubles, the size of the array, and then 3 pass-by-reference parameters called min, max, and avg.  My function must:  process the array data to find the minimum value (min), maximum value (max), and calculate the average (avg), each of which gets assigned to the corresponding reference parameter so that the calling function will be able to see those values. I am fairly new to coding and am very confused in what my error is the main function included below, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void normalizeMinMaxAvg(double data[], int size,double& min, double& 
    max, double& avg)
{
    max = 0;
    min = 0;
    //int amount = size;
    int count = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int i;
    avg = 0;

    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        count++;
        sum += i;

        if ( i > max)
        {
            i=max;
        }

        else if (i < min)
        {
            i=min;
        }
    }
    avg = sum/count;
}

int main () 
{
    double data[]={10.0,0.0,20.0,30.0};

    cout << normalizeMinMaxAvg (data, 4, min, max, avg);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Since your function doesn't return anything, you can't output directly from it.

Comment: the error that is occurring is " In function 'int main()':
46:52: error: 'avg' was not declared in this scope"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code. You need to understand how [passing arguments by reference](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) works in C++.

```
void normalizeMinMaxAvg(double data[], int size,double& min, double& max, double& avg)
```

`normalizeMinMaxAvg` doesn't return anything - note the `void` return type - it modifies 3 already existing `double` variables, so if you are going to call it form `main` you have to define those variables.

```
int main()
{
    double data[]={10.0,0.0,20.0,30.0};
    double min = 0, max = 0, avg = 0; //variables defined and initialized here
    //Note the '= 0' on all variables, it's important else they'll have random values
    normalizeMinMaxAvg(data, sizeof(data)/sizeof(data[0]), min, max, avg);

    //Your function has modified min, max, and avg, so you use them here
    std::cout << min << ", " << max << ", " << avg << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Your `normalizeMinMaxAvg` function also has problems:

```
void normalizeMinMaxAvg(double data[], int size,double& min, double& max, double& avg)
{
    if (size <= 0) //Nothing to do. Might want to add a return error code
        return;

    //0 is not a sensible value for init, what if all your values are negative?
    min = data[0];
    max = data[0];
    avg = 0;

    int sum = 0;

    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
    {
        sum += data[i];
        if ( data[i] > max) { //have to access your data by data[i]
            max=data[i]; //NOT i=max, you're assigning to max
        }

        if (data[i] < min) {
            min=data[i];
        }
    }
    avg = sum/size;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just provide variables that can be passed to that function, and output these like follows:

```
int main () 
{
    double data[]={10.0,0.0,20.0,30.0};
    double min, max, avg;

    normalizeMinMaxAvg (data, 4, min, max, avg);
    cout << "min = " << min << "\n";
    cout << "max = " << max << "\n";
    cout << "avg = " << avg << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Also inside your function use the data from the array to calculate `min` and `max`:

```
    if ( data[i] > max)
    {
        max = data[i];
    }

    else if (data[i] < min)
    {
        min = data[i];
    }
```

Comment: Min, max and avg are not returned and are on `main()` scope.

Comment: @woz they are passed by reference, the function modifies them

Comment: @woz Just as _@vu1p3n0x_ said. Stop tactical downvoting please.

Comment: @user0042 my bad. Didn't notice it was by reference. Upvoted your answer. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're not accessing your array's data. Instead you're using your iteration variable `i`. Basically, on your `normalizeMinMaxAvg` function, you should do this on your `for` loop:

```
for (i=0; i < size; i++){
    //count++;  - no need for it, you already have size!
    sum += data[i];
    if ( max > data[i]){
        max = data[i];
    }
    if (min < data[i]){
        min = data[i];
    }
}
avg = sum/size;
```

Also you need to declare your variables `min`, `max` and `avg` on your `main()` function in order to use them when you call your `normalizeMinMaxAvg` function.

Answer (score 1):

Few problems:

- deal with the empty data array case first.
- set `min` and `max` to the first element of the array (not to zero). Think about what if the numbers are all negative. Will max contain the right answer?
- You want to find the maximum and minimum elements so you have to use the data contained in `data`

  ```
  if ( data[i] > max){
      max=data[i];
  }
  ```

  Same goes for the min case.
- `normalizeMinMaxAvg` does not return so you cannot use it in a `cout` expression. You can print the parameters directly.

Here is a working version of your code.

```
void normalizeMinMaxAvg(double data[], int size,double& min, double& 
    max, double& avg)
{
    if(size<=0)
        return;
    min= max = data[0];

    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    int i;
    avg = 0;

    for (i=1; i < size; i++)
    {
        count++;
        sum += data[i];

        if ( data[i] > max)
        {
            max=data[i];
        }

        else if (data[i] < min)
        {
            min=data[i];
        }
    }
    avg = sum/(double)count;
}

int main () 
{
    double data[]={10.0,0.0,20.0,30.0};
    double min,max,avg;
    normalizeMinMaxAvg (data, 4, min, max, avg);
    cout<<min<<"  "<<max<<" "<<avg<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple things I noticed:

The values are stored in data[] so you must use data[i] in your loop to check for min, max, and to compute the average.

Also, you want to initialize min to the maximum double value so that it will be replaced by the actual minimum from the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be referencing the items in the array. So it should not just simply be i, that is just a number. It should be data[i]. This will refer to the ith element of the array data.

Answer (score 0):

Three things:

1. You have to define min, max, avg in your main() function before passing them on.
2. You can't cout << function() if it doesn't return anything.
3. In normalizeMinMaxAvg for loop, you access i (index) instead of data[i] (the data under index i in array data).